# Powershell in CruiseControl.net to backup existing folder before deploying new version of the code

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I would like to zip a bunch of files (.exe and .dll) before I overwrite them with the new build.  Is there a simple way to zip files without using some sort of dll?

Just creating a folder with the build number / date time stamp will also work great.  How do I pass parameters from the cruise control build process into my Powershell script that will do the work then?

Is this a sustainable way to do things?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use CCNET's [Package Publisher Task](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Package+Publisher) directly or zip the files via the [PowerShell Task](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/PowerShell+Task) introduced in CCNET 1.5.

Configuration sample for PowerShell Task:

```
<powershell>
  <description>Adding scheduled jobs</description>
  <scriptsDirectory>ScheduledTasks</scriptsDirectory>
  <script>CreateScheduledJobsFromListOfTasks.ps1</script>
  <buildArgs>-zipDir="C:\foo"</buildArgs>
</powershell>
```

Comment: So that is what I am trying to figure out how to do.  I have the PowerShell Task setup, and it is running a powershell script, but now I need to make the script do something.

Comment: IMO the documentation is pretty straightforward. So where is the problem? Is it PowerShell or is it CCNET? Perhaps You should consider Package Publisher...

Comment: This is one of the tasks that I have for powershell (see belowe) but in moving the files across I need to pass at least one parameter into power shell from CCNET.  And I have no idea how to achieve that.
    <powershell>
      <description>Adding scheduled jobs</description>
      <scriptsDirectory>ScheduledTasks</scriptsDirectory>
      <script>CreateScheduledJobsFromListOfTasks.ps1</script>      
    </powershell>

Comment: You could pass arguments to PowerShell via `<buildArgs>` element. I added a sample configuration.

Comment: This looks correct to me. Given the description of the problem your answer should help solve it.